# Trying to use INNER JOIN and GROUP BY SQL with SUM Function, Not Working

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, inner-join

I am not getting my head around this, and wondered if anyone may be able to help me with this.

I have 2 Tables called `RES_DATA` and `INV_DATA`

`RES_DATA` Contains my Customer as below

```
CUSTOMER ID | NAME

1, Robert
2, John
3, Peter
```

`INV_DATA` Contains their INVOICES as Below

```
INVOICE ID | CUSTOMER ID | AMOUNT

100, 1, £49.95
200, 1, £105.95
300, 2, £400.00
400, 3, £150.00
500, 1, £25.00
```

I am Trying to write a `SELECT` STATEMENT Which will give me the results as Below.

```
CUSTOMER ID | NAME | TOTAL AMOUNT

1, Robert, £180.90
2, John, £400.00
3, Peter, £150.00
```

I think I need 2 INNER JOINS Somehow to Add the tables and SUM Values of the INVOICES Table GROUPED BY the Customer Table but honestly think I am missing something. Can't even get close to the Results I need.

Comment: what kind of SQL?  SQL Server?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT a.[CUSTOMER ID], a.[NAME], SUM(b.[AMOUNT]) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT]
FROM RES_DATA a INNER JOIN INV_DATA b
ON a.[CUSTOMER ID]=b.[CUSTOMER ID]
GROUP BY a.[CUSTOMER ID], a.[NAME]
```

I tested it with SQL Fiddle against SQL Server 2008: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cad5/1

Basically what's happening here is that, because of the join, you are getting the same row on the "left" (i.e. from the `RES_DATA` table) for every row on the "right" (i.e. the `INV_DATA` table) that has the same `[CUSTOMER ID]` value.  When you group by just the columns on the left side, and then do a sum of just the `[AMOUNT]` column from the right side, it keeps the one row intact from the left side, and sums up the matching values from the right side.

Comment: The reason why a.[NAME] is also included is tuples which have those attributes are repeated. Am I right?

Comment: How would one optimize the solution, if performance is a factor?

Answer (score 10):

Two ways to do it...

GROUP BY

```
SELECT RES.[CUSTOMER ID], RES,NAME, SUM(INV.AMOUNT) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT]
FROM RES_DATA RES
JOIN INV_DATA INV ON RES.[CUSTOMER ID] INV.[CUSTOMER ID]
GROUP BY RES.[CUSTOMER ID], RES,NAME
```

OVER

```
SELECT RES.[CUSTOMER ID], RES,NAME, 
       SUM(INV.AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION RES.[CUSTOMER ID]) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT]
FROM RES_DATA RES
JOIN INV_DATA INV ON RES.[CUSTOMER ID] INV.[CUSTOMER ID]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use subquery

`SELECT * FROM RES_DATA inner join (SELECT [CUSTOMER ID], sum([TOTAL AMOUNT]) FROM INV_DATA group by [CUSTOMER ID]) T on RES_DATA.[CUSTOMER ID] = t.[CUSTOMER ID]`

Comment: This answer will have `O(n^2)` performance, as op. to a group by or over which will have `O(n)`

Comment: Indeed, but he was looking for a result, not for performance.

Comment: This answer works well when you join within the same table to get a group by within some column in the table for each line in the table.

Comment: This solution has serious performance issues. Please do not consider this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve more columns other than columns which are in group by then you can consider below query. Check it once whether it is performing well or not.

```
SELECT 
a.[CUSTOMER ID], 
a.[NAME], 
(select SUM(b.[AMOUNT]) from INV_DATA b
where b.[CUSTOMER ID] = a.[CUSTOMER ID]
GROUP BY b.[CUSTOMER ID]) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT]
FROM RES_DATA a
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT RES.[CUSTOMER ID], RES.NAME, SUM(INV.AMOUNT) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT]
FROM RES_DATA
JOIN INV_DATA ON RES.[CUSTOMER ID]=INV.[CUSTOMER ID]
GROUP BY RES.[CUSTOMER ID], RES.NAME
```

Comment: Please explain your code (even code comments are helpful).